# Help with functional equation derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**No complete Answers Please**

> The function is $e^x$, but I want to see the approach. $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$ and $f(a + b) = f(a)f(b)$.
>
> Show $f(x) = f'(x)$ without knowing its $e^x$.

I just need some **hints** and nothing else.

I tried plugging in $a=x, b = 0$ but that is useless since I get $f(x) = f(x)$.

Plugging in $a = b = x/2$ I get $f(x) = f(x/2)^2 \implies f(2x) = f(x)^2$.

Comment: Partially differentiate $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$ with respect to $a$ & set $b=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate $$f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$$ with respect to $a$ to get
$$f^{\prime}(a+b)=f^{\prime}(a)f(b)$$

Comment: Then plug in $a=0$ to get $f'(b) = f(b)$?

Comment: Yeah, thought you didn't want a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
put $a=f (1) $.

then $$f (n)=a^n .$$
$$f (x+1)=af (x)$$
by differentiation
$$f'(x+1)=af'(x)$$

$$f'(1)=af'(0)=a=f (1)$$
$$f'(2)=af'(1)=a^2=f (2) $$
...

Answer (score 1):

Given $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$ put $x=-y$. To get

> $$f(x)f(-x)=1$$

Then differentiate w.r.t. $x$ only and again put $x=-y$

> $$f'(x)f(-x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the definition of the derivative
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
With a broth of algebra, a pinch of $f(0)$, and a dash of L'Hopital's rule it's a savory dish.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = $$\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {f(x)f(h) - f(x)}{h}\\
f'(x) = f(x) \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {(f(h) - 1)}{h}$

and since

$f'(0) = f(0) = 1\\   
\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {(f(h) - 1)}{h} = 1$